Why is the button on the sidebar unclickable?
The button on the sidebar is unclickable. On my main page, the button element works clearly, but on sidebar, it is not working.
import { useContext, TouchableOpacity } from "react";
import { DataContext } from "../App";
import "./SideBar.css";

    const SideBar = () => {
      const [showModal, setShowModal] = useContext(DataContext);
      return (
        <div
          className={showModal ? "modal-dialog show" : "modal-dialog"}
          role="document"
        >
          <div className="sideBar">
            <div className="sideBarHeader">
              <h5>Add City</h5>
              <button >
                Trial
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default SideBar;


You must provide a click event to your button

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

My problem isn't about click event. I can't click to the button. You know, when you click button, background color changes. My button element act like a div element. Its background doesn't change.

Please add a click handler on button onCLick here is your updated code:
import { useContext } from "react";
import { DataContext } from "../App";
import "./SideBar.css";

const SideBar = () => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useContext(DataContext);

  const handleClick = () => {
    // Handle button click logic here
    console.log("Button clicked!");
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={showModal ? "modal-dialog show" : "modal-dialog"}
      role="document"
    >
      <div className="sideBar">
        <div className="sideBarHeader">
          <h5>Add City</h5>
          {/* Ensure button has onClick event handler */}
          <button onClick={handleClick}>
            Trial
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideBar;

